# Adding Custom View to includedView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, kotlin

I want to add a custom view into a layout, but that layout is included in another layout that's included in another layout.
My problem is that my custom view it's not being inflated to the layout because Android can't find the id to my custom layout.

Here is the Code for my custom Layout as also it's XML code.

Class:

```
class PackShotView(ctx : Context, attrs : AttributeSet?, defStyle : Int) : RelativeLayout(ctx,attrs,defStyle) {

        init {
            inflate(context, R.layout.pack_shot_view,this)
            (findViewById<NetworkImageView>(R.id.packShotImage) as NetworkImageView).setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.pack_shot_empty)
            (findViewById<NetworkImageView>(R.id.packShotImage) as NetworkImageView).setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.pack_shot_empty)

            if(isInEditMode){
                (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.data) as TextView).text = context.getString(R.string.data_default_text)
                (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.newsTitle) as TextView).text = context.getString(R.string.news_title_default)
            }
        }

        constructor(ctx: Context) : this(ctx, null, 0)
        constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(ctx,attrs,0)

        fun setNewsInfo(news: News?,
                        imageLoader: ImageLoader,
                        urlBuilder: String?){
            (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.data) as TextView).text = news?.date
            (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.newsTitle) as TextView).text = news?.name
            news?.image?.let {
                Log.v(context.getString(R.string.app_name),"Displaying image from URL $urlBuilder")
                (findViewById<NetworkImageView>(R.id.packShotImage) as NetworkImageView).setImageUrl(urlBuilder,imageLoader)
            }
        }
    }
```

XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:showIn="@layout/content_main"
        tools:context=".Presentation.MainActivity">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/packShotImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            tools:background="@drawable/pack_shot_empty" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            tools:text="Data" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/packShotImage"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            tools:text="Text" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Layout i want to have the custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="musicristo.pt.app.Presentation.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/youtube"
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Segue-nos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />



        <musicristo.pt.app.Presentation.Widget.PackShotView
            android:id="@+id/packShot"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

        </musicristo.pt.app.Presentation.Widget.PackShotView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextBackground"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground_edit_text_holo_light"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:queryHint="Pesquise um cântico..."
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray">
        </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The parent of the above layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        tools:context="musicristo.pt.app.Presentation.MainActivity">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main"
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </include>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: whats the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: How do i see that?

Comment: in the terminal window, more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)

Comment: humm it says that adb is not a recognized command, and my App won't even start so maybe there is no output

Comment: `adb`, not `abd`

Comment: i can't see any output

Comment: so what is says? nothing? just silence?

Comment: for example `adb shell ls /` - no output at all?

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I could be doing it the wrong way tho

Comment: i already sent you a link with more info about `adb`

Comment: i've seen that and i've installed the tools but it still does not shows anything

Comment: i dont think you are superman ;-) superman would do that with no problems...

Comment: yeah sry about that :(

Comment: ok so did you locate `adb` tool? just call it with the full path

Comment: that's the problem, i can't locate it

Comment: Try %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: Found it! now what?

Comment: @TrentonTelge got the command running and working. I'm suppose to search for really? I got the View hierarchy and other bunch of stuff